# Pass class object to service

Tags: java, android

I'm new in android and java and encountered with one issue. I have an activity with methods and I want to use them in background. For background I used a Service class. The problem is that I cannot pass activity object to service constructor because it must not contains any params in it. I read how to send strings and doubles via intend but I cannot find how to pass activity class.

```js
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    }

    public void toast(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

//---------------------------------------

public class MyService extends Service
{
    private MainActivity main;

    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        main.toast("test");    // <- here I want to use some method
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello please see below steps sure help you.

**Step 1.** Define an interface your Service will use to communicate events:

```
public interface ServiceCallbacks {
    void Showtoast(String msg);
}
```

**Step 2.** Write your Service class. Your Activity will bind to this service. In addition, we will add a method to set the ServiceCallbacks.

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    // Binder given to clients 
    private final IBinder binder = new LocalBinder();
    // Registered callbacks 
    private ServiceCallbacks serviceCallbacks;


    // Class used for the client Binder. 
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        MyService getService() { 
            // Return this instance of MyService so clients can call public methods 
            return MyService.this;
        } 
    } 

    @Override 
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    } 

    public void setCallbacks(ServiceCallbacks callbacks) {
        serviceCallbacks = callbacks;
    } 
}
```

**Step 3.** Write your Activity class following the same guide, but also make it implement your ServiceCallbacks interface. When you bind/unbind from the Service, you will register/unregister it by calling setCallbacks on the Service.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements ServiceCallbacks {
    private MyService service;
    private boolean bound = false;

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ......
    } 

    @Override 
    protected void onStart() { 
        super.onStart(); 
        // bind to Service 
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    } 

    @Override 
    protected void onStop() { 
        super.onStop(); 
        // Unbind from service 
        if (bound) {
            service.setCallbacks(null); // unregister
            unbindService(serviceConnection);
            bound = false;
        } 
    } 

    /** Callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */ 
    private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override 
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                IBinder service) {
            // cast the IBinder and get MyService instance 
            LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
            service = binder.getService();
            bound = true;
            service.setCallbacks(this); // register
        } 

        @Override 
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            bound = false;
        } 
    }; 

    /* Defined by ServiceCallbacks interface */ 
    @Override 
    public void Showtoast(String message) { 
         Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 
}
```

Thank you let me know if you any question.

Comment: thanks, only an error in this string "service.setCallbacks(this); // register" because the same name for MyService and local IBinder

Comment: You would also need something like MyActivity self = this and change service.setCallback(this) to service.setCallback(self)

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated? You can show toast from service easily.
So you can place you code into service's onCreate method

```
Toast.makeText(this, "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: toast here only for example, idea is to call activity methods from the service

Comment: What actually do you need? Why that logic should be exactly inside Activity?